# Use types from one module for another

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped, babylonjs

I'm using Babylonjs with the Rollupjs together with typescript.

[image: babylon.d.ts]

Babylonjs has typings bundled with the package so when I import it like this:

```
import { ArcRotateCamera, Engine, SceneLoader, Vector3 } from "babylonjs";
```

I get all of the typing information and type-checking from typescript, however, due to (I think) how **babylon.js** is bundled - Rollup cannot bundle it throwing errors:

> 1: import { ArcRotateCamera, Engine, SceneLoader, Vector3 } from "babylonjs";
>
> 2: import "babylonjs-loaders";
>
> 3: import React from "react";
>
> Error: 'Engine' is not exported by node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.js

To fix rollup bundling I need to change imports to:

```
import { ArcRotateCamera, Engine, SceneLoader, Vector3 } from "babylonjs/es6";
```

but then I lose all of the typing information...

So my quickest solution to that would be to somehow instruct typescript that **babylon.d.ts** applies also to **babylonjs/es6.js**.

P.S 
these named import are all correct and working because component works when I use it with @storybook (which loads it with webpack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice how the `babylonjs` module is declared in `babylon.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'babylonjs' { 
    export = BABYLON; 
}
declare module BABYLON {
    // Many declarations...
}
```

To associate the same declarations with the `babylonjs/es6` module name, all you have to do is follow the same format and add a module declaration to a new file in your project:

```
declare module 'babylonjs/es6' { 
    export = BABYLON; 
}
```

(Adding this code inside another module file will not work because then it will be treated as a module augmentation instead of a module declaration.)

Consider filing an issue to have this change made in the original `babylonjs` package.

Comment: Thanks. I get the answer that they are working on full es6 support so I’m pretty sure they will fix it then.